# I am getting 2 outputs for extremely long strings

Tags: java, string, netbeans, output

I have a program that involves parsing strings that represent nucleotides.

When I use a small nucleotide string (basically, a small DNA strand) i.e. 'input' is small enough, I get one output:

However, when I use a loooooooooooooooong string. e.g. 10000 nucleotides long (which I actually use) , I end up with 2 outputs :O

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A39um.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnNcG.png

Source code: I only added the functions that I was actually using in the main class.

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    String input = "Blah Blah";
    System.out.println(translate(input));
}

public static String codon (String codon_input)
/* Returns the amino acid alphabet corresponding to entered codon 
   (3 nucleotide string) in String format. */        
{
    if (codon_input.substring(0,2).equals("GC"))
    {
        return "A";
    }
    else if (codon_input.equals("UGU") || codon_input.equals("UGC"))
    {
        return "C";
    }
    else if (codon_input.equals("GAU") || codon_input.equals("GAC"))
    {
        return "D";
    }
    else if (codon_input.equals("GAA") || codon_input.equals("GAG"))
    {
        return "E";
    }
    else if (codon_input.equals("UUU") || codon_input.equals("UUC"))
    {
        return "F";
    }
    else if (codon_input.substring(0,2).equals("GG"))
    {
        return "G";
    }
    else if (codon_input.equals("CAU") || codon_input.equals("CAC"))
    {
        return "H";
    }
    else if (codon_input.substring(0,2).equals("AU") && !codon_input.equals("AUG"))
    {
        return "I";
    }
    else if (codon_input.equals("AAA") || codon_input.equals("AAG"))
    {
        return "K";
    }
    else if (codon_input.substring(0,2).equals("CU") || codon_input.equals("UUA") || codon_input.equals("UUG"))
    {
        return "L";
    }
    else if (codon_input.equals("AUG"))
    {
        return "M";
    }
    else if (codon_input.equals("AAU") || codon_input.equals("AAC"))
    {
        return "N";
    }
    else if (codon_input.substring(0,2).equals("CC"))
    {
        return "P";
    }
    else if (codon_input.equals("CAA") || codon_input.equals("CAG"))
    {
        return "Q";
    }
    else if (codon_input.substring(0,2).equals("CG") || codon_input.equals("AGA") || codon_input.equals("AGG"))
    {
        return "R";
    }
    else if (codon_input.substring(0,2).equals("UC") || codon_input.equals("AGU") || codon_input.equals("AGC"))
    {
        return "S";
    }
    else if (codon_input.substring(0,2).equals("AC"))
    {
        return "T";
    }
    else if (codon_input.substring(0,2).equals("GU"))
    {
        return "V";
    }
    else if (codon_input.equals("UGG"))
    {
        return "W";
    }
    else if (codon_input.equals("UAU") || codon_input.equals("UAC"))
    {
        return "Y";
    }
    else if (codon_input.equals("UAA") || codon_input.equals("UAG") || codon_input.equals("UGA"))
    {
        return "Stop";
    }
    return "-";
}

public static String translate (String tran_input)
/* Converts an RNA strand into an amino acid strand using codon() */
{
    String tran_output = "";
    int tran_length = tran_input.length();
    int tran_cursor = 0;
    while (tran_cursor < tran_length - 2)
    {
        if (codon(tran_input.substring(tran_cursor, tran_cursor + 3)).equals("Stop"))
        {
            return tran_output;
        }
        else
        {
            tran_output = tran_output + codon(tran_input.substring(tran_cursor, tran_cursor + 3));
        }
        tran_cursor = tran_cursor + 3;
    }
    return tran_output;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not just the IDE breaking a very long line into two? Try to copy-paste into another editor and check how it looks there.

Comment: @Drux No, it's not. It is possible to enable word wrapping and enable the IDE to do that to the output but no, in this case, the IDE is just giving 2 **exactly similar** outputs.

Comment: The accepted answer says just that, so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console can only have so many characters in one line. According to another post mac can have 2047 (I don't know what it is on netbeans). Therefore, I think your console is just moving to the next line because it is so long. I would suggest just outputting to a file.

Comment: That was my initial thought too, but it doesn't explain why the two lines are identical (as far as we can see from the screenshot). Outputting to a file is good anyway.

Comment: I don't really need to save the answer to a file :/ Just need to copy it and submit it online. This is probably just a bug in netbeans and not with my code, I guess. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this not the kind of data you want to output to an external log file to keep on record? Like the above user said, format your data and save it to a nice file for readability.

Comment: That isn't much of a solution. There should be a way to output on the console without any errors. (Hate you netbeans!) Well, at least the problem isn't with my code so, I have that going for me, I guess :)